# IMAP COPY command - uid and Message-Id

Tags: copy, imap, fetch

I understood that UID changes but the Message-Id will not be changed during any operation on a particular mail. However, after some operations I came up with this case:

Lets assume I have a `total of 2000 emails` in my `INBOX`. If I copy the `1000th` email with `UID 1000` and `Message-Id 1000` to my `Trash` mailbox and then I copy that back to the `INBOX`, the UID will change to 2000 and Message-Id to 2000; the current for that folder. Then, regardless of the date that email will be at the top.

Now the question is, if I `. fetch 1990:2000 fast` (the last 10 emails), I'll get the that particular email among the 10 fetched. How would you fetch the last 10 based on the date without having to fetch 2000 emails and then sort them out by date?

Comment: Sergey, you've misunderstood.  There are 3 pieces of data involved here.  A message's UID is constant as long as it's in the folder (and as long as the folder's UIDVALIDITY doesn't change).  A message's sequence number is its position in a UID-ordered message list -- so if you delete message 1 from the folder, all the UIDs remain unchanged but each remaining message's sequence number drops by 1.  And the Message-ID **header** of the message is truly invariant -- move it to Trash and back, but it still has the same Message-ID header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IMAP server supports it, you can use the SORT command for this, as descibed in [RFC 5256](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256.txt). The specific command you're looking for is probably:

```
C: A11 SORT (REVERSE DATE) UTF-8 ALL
S: * SORT 5 3 4 1 2
S: A11 OK SORT completed
```

The server response is a list of message sequence numbers that you can use for a subsequent fetch.

---

If your server supports the `SORT` extension (modern IMAP servers do), it will be announced in response to the `CAPABILITY` command. Here's a response from the ancient version of Courier-IMAP I'm running:

```
CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES
  SORT QUOTA LOGIN IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION STARTTLS
```

Comment: Unfortunately Gmail does not seem to support it. `* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE` Any alternatives? thanks

Comment: @Sergey: no, if the IMAP server lacks support for server-side sorting, your only option is to fetch and sort them yourself. You don't need to download entire messages, but can fetch only their dates and UIDs.

Comment: thanks! thats what I was afraid of. I'm wondering how long it would take to fetch only their dates and UIDs on 10K messages

Comment: @Sergey: It's usually pretty fast.  `UID FETCH 1:* INTERNALDATE` will give you the UIDs and received dates for all the messages in the folder.